# Can we pleeease buy the space.se domain name?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Space.se seems to be an available domain name. It doesn't load any site and isn't parked anywhere. When I try to go to it I just get a 'this site can't be reached' error.
It's for sites in Sweden, but maybe we could make that work.

[image]

Maybe it doesn't seem like a big deal, but it would eliminate 14 characters from the domain, allowing it to be referred to with much less of a mouthful verbally, not just be nicely shorter for tweets and such.

I like to refer to (cough) space.se questions when I post on Twitter sometimes, and so to me this seems like it would be a significant improvement. I'm sure it could be hard to arrange. Still. I'm just askin'.

Comment: I'm not sure it would make business sense for the StackExchange company.  Most of their sites would make sense as a Swedish domain which you describe.  It costs money to register a domain; the higher traffic SE sites are more likely to recoup this cost.  So, I don't see the SE company doing this.  The alternative is for someone else to donate money and just do it.  I'm not opposed to someone doing that.

Comment: @DrSheldon Oh yeah, for sure the company wouldn't do it. But space.stackexchange is one of many sites they run that aren't for profit really. So, if we gave them a proposition, there is a teeny outside chance they might let us do something on our own account.

Comment: Legal/trademark questions aside, there's no technical reason someone couldn't purchase the domain of their own accord and simply redirect it.

Comment: @Tristan that would work fine, but it wouldn't work for more than the homepage, would it? It couldn't be used for generally shortening addresses, right?

Comment: Correct.  You could potentially write a URL shortener for it, or you could just forward the rest of the URL fairly straightforwardly though.  Depends on how much it's worth for you I guess

Comment: FYI space.se is owned by [Ruag](https://www.ruag.com) you can look it up [here](https://internetstiftelsen.se/en/domains/)

Comment: @MarkOmo yeah ok. I should have known it was too good to be true.

Comment: The company blog is currently running a [series on software in space](https://stackoverflow.blog/tag/software-in-space/), and there are zero mentions of space.stackexchange.  **The company does not even know we exist.**

Comment: Oh, sure they do. They just wouldn't come to us to help with anything like that.

Comment: @DrSheldon The company hardly knows *anything* outside StackOverflow exists...